# Get Claw-Mail to read Exchange Calendar

Tags: claws-mail

I recently installed Claw-Mail and DavMail to talk to the office Exchange server to my Ubuntu workstation. The mail part works really well.

I installed the vCalendar plugin in Claws-mail to read my Exchange Calendar information and that does not work. I used [DavMail's example of Thunderbird](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/thunderbirdcalendarsetup.html) as my guide.

I right-clicked and went to "Subscribe to WebCal" and have tried all sorts of URL formats:

```
   http://localhost:1080/users/mail@company.com/calendar
```

Claws-Mail error: 401 (Authorisation required)

```
  http://user@localhost:1080/users/mail@company.com/calendar
```

Claws-Mail error: 401 (Authorisation required)

```
http://user:password@localhost:1080/users/mail@company.com/calendar
```

Claws-Mail error: This URL does not look like a WebCal URL ... 404

My password has a non-alphanumeric character so maybe that through it off.

Has anyone gotten this to work in Claw-Mail/vCalendar?